# Is it possible to insert random numbers in an org table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have an `org-mode` table

```
|----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----|
| 40 | 40 | 30 | 20 | 50 | 50 | 100 | 100 | 200 |
|----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----|
|    |    |    |    |    |    |     |     |     |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |     |     |     |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |     |     |     |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |     |     |     |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |     |     |     |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |     |     |     |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |     |     |     |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |     |     |     |
|    |    |    |    |    |    |     |     |     |
|----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----|
```

I'd like to fill in the empty cells each with a random integer between `0` and the top number of each column. Is this possible?

I'm very new to `emacs` and `org-mode` but really excited about learning!

Comment: You could also use R or any other langauge to build the table and return it as an org table using babel. I mentioned R since it has excellent statistical capabilities out of box and it is a GNU project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following formula will do the trick:

```
#+TBLFM: @2$<..@>$>=random(@1)
```

This means: all rows 2 onwards, and all columns, get a random number in the range of the first row.

Results will be integers. If you want real numbers, do `random(@1 * 1.0)`.